# How did an immutable reference in a slice get updated? Why doesn't it change the referenced variable's value?

Tags: rust, slice

I was going through the Rust documentation where I read about [slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html). As per the page's text, a slice is an immutable reference:

> This is also why string literals are immutable; &str is an immutable reference.

I would expect 2 things in below code:

- `yetnewstring = "we";` to give a compile time error
- Even if I'm wrong about the above, I still expect the output of the last print statement for `newstring2` to be `westtheSlice`.

How does the below code work?

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut newstring2: String; //declare new mutable string
    newstring2 = String::from("Hello");    // add a value to it 
    println!("this is new newstring: {}", newstring2); // output = Hello

    let mut yetnewstring = test123(&mut newstring2); // pass a mutable reference of newstring2 , and get back a string literal
    println!("this is yetnewstring :{}", yetnewstring); // output = "te"
    yetnewstring = "we"; // how come this is mutable now ? arent string literals immutable?
    println!("this is the Changed yetnewstring  :{}", yetnewstring); // output = "we"
    println!("this is newstring2 after change of yetnewstring = 'we' : {}" , newstring2); // output  = "testtheSlice"
    // if string literal yetnewstring was reference to a slice of  newstring2 ,
    //then shouldnt above  output have to be :"westtheSlice"
}

fn test123(s: &mut String) -> &str {
     *s = String::from("testtheSlice");  
    &s[0..2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks , the answers in the post are very infromative. So yes,  `*s =  String::from("testtheSlice");`  cahnges :"Hello" to "testtheSlice". But I'm confused about the remaining part of code . How is the  `yetnewstring = test123(&mut newstring2);` takings value from `newstring2 ` ? Also if  `yetnewstring` is a mutable variable referring to a `&str` type , does it mean it can change the value held by `&str` that its referring to ? And if it is , why  dint `newstring2 `'s value change in that case after we updated value of `yetnewstring ` to "we"?

Comment: That aside, `&str` is not a string literal. A string literal is `&str` (`&'static str` specifically) but there are lots of ways to create an `&str` besides that, it's just a non-owning reference to string data which lives *somewhere*.

Comment: " Also if yetnewstring is a mutable variable referring to a &str type , does it mean it can change the value held by &str that its referring to ?" no, you can change what it's referring to to be an other thing, but you can't change the *contents* of what it's referring to.

Comment: "why dint newstring2 's value change in that case after we updated value of yetnewstring to "we"?" because you just changed what `yetnewstring` points to. `newstring2` independently pointed to the same place, but you didn't (and could not) change the pointee.

Comment: Think of it this way: Harold and Kumar both have a car. It's the same car, which they share. Kumar gets a new car, Kumar's car is different than it used to be, but it's Kumar which changed, not the car itself, so Harold and their (now exclusive) car is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers  Masklinn , really helpful

Answer (score 2):

`yetnewstring`'s type is `&str`, only the *binding* is mutable. The assignment is valid because you're assigning another `&str` value to a `&str` variable, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: If the bindling is mutable,  that means its editing the value of  `newstring2 ` under the hood in that case? Then shouldnt the last print statement output "westtheSlice"?

Comment: It is not modifying `newstring2`. You are modifying `yetnewstring` to reference a string literal, rather than a portion of `newstring2`. In other words, you are changing what `newstring2` is pointing to, not the value of that.